# React is not routing to the destination page -react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

One of my routes is not showing the destination pages . 
Also ,without the ":" version (which is /id: ) the hardcoded path works, So I guess the problem lies with the ( some_variable: version of routing ). Do explain : version as well

```
<Route path="/tournament/register/id:" exact component={RegisterTournament}/>
```

This is the main page where the routing happens App.js

```
....all imports....

const App=()=>{
  return (
    <div className="App" >  
        <Router history={History}>
            <div>
                <Header/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/tournaments" exact component={Tournament}/>
                    <Route path="/myTournaments" exact component={MyTournaments}/>
                    <Route path="/profile" exact component={Profile}/>
                    <Route path="/help" exact component={Help}/>
                    <Route path="/signIn" exact component={SignIn}/>
                    <Route path="/register" exact component={Register}/>
                    <Route path="/results" exact component={Results}/>
                    <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard}/>
                    <Route path="/tournament/register/:id" exact component={RegisterTournament}/>
                    <Route path="/tournament/register/:id/summary/" exact component={RegistrationSummary}/>
                </Switch>
            </div>       
        </Router>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is the function of the component where I invoke that route

```
....
....

const registerTournament=({tournament})=>{
        console.log(tournament);
        dispatch({type:ActionTypes.SET_TOURNAMENT_DATA,payload:tournament});
        history.push(`/tournament/register/${tournament.tournament_id}`);

    }
....
....
```

when the history.push() above , the page shows blank , but the URL shows correctly as http://localhost:3000/tournament/register/Aeroflot%20Open%20B%202020
but the particular component is not showing /rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route matcher is wrong for that route.
You should place the colon after the slash

`<Route path="/tournament/register/:id" exact component={RegisterTournament}/>`

Do the same for the summary route too

Comment: Inside your register tournament component, log the value of `props.match.params.id` to the console, then try opening this in your browser - http://localhost:3000/tournament/register/testing

Comment: i tried to console log the value of props.match.param.id as you said ,it showed undefined and when opened the URL you said , it still didn't load the page

Comment: Here's a sandbox for you to check out - https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-christian-2wtvb?file=/src/App.js